# Suggestions on group SMS implementation on iOS 10+?

Tags: android, ios, sms, limit

I just found out that carriers limit number of recipients of SMS to 10. As a result in my app I am not able to SMS a group of people consisting of more than 10 people. At least, I can not do this easily and user friendly. I am aware of a couple of apps that do similar thing (GroupMe for example) do they go through their server to actually send out an SMS? Can anyone recommend a technical solution around this problem? Anyway to solve it in-app? In app I do have all the phone numbers that are to be messaged and user is not involved in selecting them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the only way to do this is through the use of SMS gateway either posting from the app or more probably a better idea through app->myserver->sms gateway.
Restriction is AT&T specific it seems as it seems to work fine on Verizon.